# how to combine non ascii char with string in python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, encoding, ascii, decoding

I have a string 'My Name' and variable customerName with 'sünil' data. I want to combine both so I tried

```
'My Name' + customerName
```

but this is showing error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

then I tried

```
'My Name' + encodeStr(customerName)
```

but this is showing

```
My Name s\x3\xenil
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the name like this.

```
comibined_name = 'My Name' + customerName
```

To **print** it, you need to encode it so that it matched the encoding you want to print to. That is a bit confusing and it's possible that your output can't handle utf-8 chars.

If your script starts with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
comibined_name = 'My Name' + 'Sünil'.decode('utf-8')
```

you can print

```
print('My Name' + customerName)
```

See [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to learn why.

Under windows, if you save your source in utf-8 format, this example
works:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
comibined_name = 'My Name ' + 'Sünil'.decode('utf-8')

print(comibined_name)
```

Comment: not working. even I tried unicode(customerName,'utf-8').. it is showing TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Comment: fixed some typos, above. The whole unicode / ascii thing is difficult to get right in python2. If you need to find out why you can't print to utf-8 in your operating system you will need to specify exact infos about your environment.